# Android app to kill background applications?

Tags: android, task-management

My Android phone, a Samsung Galaxy Note 5, is getting more and more slower. I bought it less than a year ago.

I wonder if there is any convenient app that can kill all background apps quickly without needing to root my phone.

Comment: You can use Greenify without root privilegeGreenify w/o root privilage  will works only on user apps.AFAIK, in order to kill background activities of system app you must need to root.You can _disable_ (settings->app) the app that you're not using(you can call them bloatware because samsung devices are comes with bloatwares).Tip:- Just clear device cache by using stock recovery

Comment: Killing background processes *might* help – but it might also make things worse. May I suggest to first check our Android sister-site on how to best deal with the situation? Starter: [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575)

Comment: @Izzy I am looking for a similar app. I just got new phone - cheaply - with not a lot of RAM. If I play poker, then switch to something else, the poker app in background is taking half my RAM.

I want an app where i can selectively say "apps x, y & z should never be in background. Terminate them if I switch away". This question is 4 years old, can I post another? I don't see Greenify or your link to the Android site helping me, it's just a cheap phone

Comment: If you'd asked this on Android.SE, I might have suggested enabling developer options and look for the corresponding setting (yes, there is one like "always finish", I'd need to check the exact name). But that would affect all apps. Well… but why shouldn't you be allowed to ask a different question here? You don't want to "kill all background apps", but want to have selected apps always "terminate" when leaving. Sounds like something a little different, right? You can link here and explain why it doesn't fully fit your needs ;)